SnowSQL doesn't raise error code > 0 when it tries to copy data
I have a few "Execute Process Tasks" in my SSIS package to import data from SQL Server tables into Snowflake. These are these tasks:

Create Staging
Upload CSV files from my Windows computer to the staging
COPY INTO from the staging to my Snowflake table

This works most of the time, but sometimes, I get below errors in the SnowSQL log file, but the error code returned to the SSIS package (caller) is still zero which causes my error handling procedure not to fire to capture the error.
I added exit_on_error=true in the connection config file but that didn't help.
Below is a sample error message captured in the log file. I expect to get an error code greater than zero when an error happens!
2024-10-12 22:36:03,548 (27156/MainThread) __main__ ERROR      eventloop:858  - sql: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eventloop.py", line 753, in run_cli
  File "cli\sqlexecute.py", line 491, in run
  File "cli\sqlexecute.py", line 574, in execute_normal_sql
  File "connector\cursor.py", line 1080, in execute
  File "connector\errors.py", line 290, in errorhandler_wrapper
  File "connector\errors.py", line 345, in hand_to_other_handler
  File "connector\errors.py", line 221, in default_errorhandler
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 100066 (22000): 01b7a64c-0002-1aea-0000-cddd06fb4982: Found character '&' instead of record delimiter '\n'
  File 'insert_36257_EnvTr.csv.gz', line 95341, character 86
  Row 95340, column "EnvTr"["VALUE":5]
  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

